# vb6 with timer in flash issue

Tags: flash, vb6

I would like to run flash file in vb6.

The flash is a timer that shows a pie and counter to display the time and it used an internal timer.

I'm trtying to load the swf file but it doesn't start.

what could be the problem??

this is the code (a very simple code):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Shockwaveflash1.Movie = App.Path & "/Timer.swf"
   Shockwaveflash1.Play
End Sub
```

Comment: which OCX did you add to your project to play the .SWF file ?

Comment: Your piece of code is correct. Only problem could be that it is not able to find the file. Ensure that Timer.swf is available in App.Path

Comment: It is. I saw that it work with another swf that not included an internal timer.

Comment: Have you tested your `SWF` by dragging it onto a web browser?

Comment: Yes it's work good.
If I used an internal timer should I need to change some settings in vb6?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this problem.

First of all VB6 support only Action Script 1 and flash player 6.

So, there is no timer in this version.

I fixed it by write frame after frame with FPS (frame per seconds) = 1.00.

Thanks anyway.